# Installing a shelf in the bathroom

Tags: bathroom, mounting, shelf

I am trying to mount the following shelf in my bathroom:
[image: shelf]

Backside of shelf:
[image: hook]

The current screws I have for the shelf:
[image: screws]

Close up:
[image: closeup]

My question:

- Are those the correct screws? Do they fit? Seems really close..
- Can I drill without damaging the tiles?

If it is a bad idea I can mount the shelf in the kitchen but I prefer bathroom.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. It would be a good idea to [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how our site operates. Would this shelf be mounted in a wet location in the bathroom (i.e. the shower)?

Comment: We can not tell if the screw head will fit in the keyhole opening, You will have to open the package and check. Drilling through the tile will require a special drill bit the correct size for the anchors you have, i prefer a diamond encrusted hole saw bit.

Answer (score 1):

The flathead of the screw needs to fit into the keyhole bracket on the shelf and we can't tell whether it would fit or not without the measurements of the bracket.

Even if you could drill the holes in the grout lines, you would probably nick or crack a tile. I would mount that shelf in the kitchen and get a bathroom shelf constructed of a PVC material and use some heavy duty two-sided tape to secure it to the wall.